# How are HashAggregate row estimates calculated?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, explain, postgresql-12

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT foo.*
FROM   foo
WHERE  foo."id" IN ((SELECT bar."id"
                     FROM   bar
                     WHERE  bar.user_id IN ( 100, 102 ))
                    UNION ALL
                    (SELECT bar."id"
                     FROM   bar
                     WHERE  bar.uploaded_by_id = 903))
       AND foo.user_id = 100
ORDER  BY foo.id DESC
```

**This is a modified and simplified toy query, please do not focus on optimizing it.**

It generates these EXPLAIN ANALZYE PLANS:

```
Sort  (cost=136893.72..136893.84 rows=238 width=2098) (actual time=641.159..647.248 rows=39120 loops=1)
  Sort Key: foo.id DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 78095kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=136067.75..136891.84 rows=238 width=2098) (actual time=93.061..553.251 rows=39120 loops=1)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=136067.64..136068.24 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=92.999..118.606 rows=96104 loops=1)
              Group Key: bar.id
              ->  Append  (cost=0.11..135968.18 rows=198925 width=8) (actual time=0.015..39.862 rows=192076 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using <index> on bar  (cost=0.11..68763.62 rows=99521 width=8) (actual time=0.015..14.323 rows=96104 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{100,102}'::bigint[]))
                    ->  Index Only Scan using <index> on bar_1  (cost=0.11..66309.40 rows=99404 width=8) (actual time=0.017..14.379 rows=95972 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (uploaded_by_id = 903)
        ->  Index Scan using <Index> on foo  (cost=0.11..4.12 rows=1 width=2098) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=96104)
              Index Cond: (id = bar.id)
              Filter: (user_id = 100)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.556 ms
Execution Time: 654.884 ms
```

Please focus specifically on these node:

```
->  HashAggregate  (cost=136067.64..136068.24 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=92.999..118.606 rows=96104 loops=1)
      Group Key: bar.id
      ->  Append  (cost=0.11..135968.18 rows=198925 width=8) (actual time=0.015..39.862 rows=192076 loops=1)
            ->  Index Only Scan using <index> on bar  (cost=0.11..68763.62 rows=99521 width=8) (actual time=0.015..14.323 rows=96104 loops=1)
            ->  Index Only Scan using <index> on bar_1  (cost=0.11..66309.40 rows=99404 width=8) (actual time=0.017..14.379 rows=95972 loops=1)
```

HashAggregate suggests there will only be 200 rows returned, even though both Index Only Scans estimate there will be 100k each, and the Append rightfully expects 200k rows will be returned. Because HashAggregate presumes it will only have 200 distinct values in the end, the plan uses an Nested Loop which grossly underperforms.
Changing the UNION ALL to an UNION improves the plan massively, because the HashAggregate actually has an more realistic row estimate (200k vs 100k real) and it doesn't choose an Nested Loop anymore.

Aside all that, my question is: How exactly is the row estimate here calculated, and why is it so far off? How can I make it get an better estimation for the UNION ALL query?

Comment: Why use an UNION ALL to begin with? This could be simplified to `where foo.id in (SELECT bar.id FROM bar WHERE  bar.user_id IN (100, 102) or bar.uploaded_by_id = 903)`

Comment: I have explicitly stated that this is a modified and simplified toy query.

Answer (score 2):

Row estimates come first, they don't depend on the node type.  So a group aggregate (aka ordered aggregate) that aggregates the same data would have the same row estimate.

200 is the default row estimate used for aggregates when it can't figure out how to come up with something specific, so I bet that is what is happening here.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Why would Group Aggregate be failing to estimate the amount of rows? The table is well-indexed, and it can already infer in the inner nodes how many distinct entries there must be (because it's getting the primary keys), so why is that information being lost between the Group Aggregate and the Append? Is it, simply said, just not implemented to work that way to pass down the information like this?